# Query in For loop

Tags: procedural-programming, iteration

*(I did not know how to write this properly. Excuse me for that.)*

```
For[x = 0.1, x < 3.5, x = x + 0.1,
 
 For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,

  If[y1[[i]] != 0, 
   s1 = k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2 + 2*k*gm + wm^2; 
   s2 = (k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2)*gm + 2*k*wm^2; 
   s3 = (k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2)*(wm^2) - (d - (g1^2*
          y1[[i]]/wm))*wm*(g1^2)*(2*y1[[i]]), Continue[]];
```

Here in place of Continue I want to go back to my inner loop ,i.e , if this If is not satisfied I want the inner for loop to run again. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Use `Do` instead of `For` (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several things wrong:

- The "Continue[]" is not needed
- You need 2 closing brackets at the end.
- y1 should be a vector with values. y[[1]],y[[2]], y[[3] are not specified
- I added two print statement in order that you can see what is going on

  y1 = {1, 0, 2};

  For[x = 0.1, x < 3.5, x = x + 0.1, For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,

  ```
  Print["{x,i}=", {x, i}];

  If[y1[[i]] != 0,
   Print["inside inner loop"]; 
   s1 = k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2 + 2*k*gm + wm^2;
   s2 = (k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2)*gm + 2*k*wm^2;
   s3 = (k^2 + (d - ((g1^2)*y1[[i]]/wm))^2)*(wm^2) - (d - (g1^2*
          y1[[i]]/wm))*wm*(g1^2)*(2*y1[[i]])]]]
  ```